# Is it possible to have more outposts?

Tags: state-of-decay, state-of-decay-breakdown

In State of Decay: Breakdown, I used all of remaining outposts on the ‎Snyder Trucking Warehouse. I want to have more outposts. Is it possible? (Even with hacks and mods.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These mods should help:

- [**Increased Outpost Limit**](https://forums.undeadlabs.com/threads/increased-outpost-limit-mod.34185/).

  > What I did is increased the outpost limit to 10. It's possible to increase even more, but on screen it will only show 10. The file that I'll upload will allow for 10 outposts instead of the usual 8. This will only work for medium size bases, any base that requires 12 people will be able to have 10 outposts.
- [**George Romero Mod**](http://www.nexusmods.com/stateofdecay/mods/4/?) (an overhaul mod) - aside from many changes, it increases allowed number of outposts to 18.